# 3 dimensional dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

```
subjects = {
    0:9,'fail': 0,
   9:14, 'pass': 25,
   15:17, 'merit': 40,
    18:20,'Distinction': 50
}
```

I want the dictionary above to contain 3 dimensions. user input will be between the initial numbers. depending what number the user enters the following message should be displayed. eg. 4  is a fail worth 0 points , 10 is a pass worth 25 points and so on.

```
inputs = ['irish','english','french','italian','dutch','german']
for i in range(1, 7):
    inputs.append(raw_input('Enter mark for {}: '.format(i)))
```

I want the loop to ask enter mark for irish etc

```
print sum(subjects[name][value] for name in inputs)
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary stores its values based on a hash of the keys.

This means a dictionary lookup only returns entries whose keys **exactly** match the one used in the lookup.

You cannot have a key be "any number in the range 3 to 5" and expect a lookup for "4" to hit.

However, what you can do is duplicate the dictionary entries:

```
subject_ranges = [(0, 8, 'fail', 0),
                  (9, 14, 'pass', 25),
                  (15, 17, 'merit', 40),
                  (18, 20, 'Distinction', 50)]
subjects = {}
for low, high, descr, points in subject_ranges:
   for score in range(low, high+1):
      subjects[score] = {'description': descr, 'value': points}
```

And collect the input like this:

```
input_names = ['irish','english','french','italian','dutch','german']
scores = []
for i in range(len(input_names)):
    scores.append(int(raw_input('Enter mark for %s: ' % input_names[i])))
```

Now this code will work to print the total score as you wished:

```
print sum(subjects[score]['value'] for score in scores)
```

This is **not** a "3-dimensional dictionary", nor anything like it. It's a dictionary whose keys are integers and whose values are two-element dictionaries (you could use NamedTuple if you wished). But from your question, it doesn't look like you actually needed anything more sophisticated than this.

Comment: the code works well however how do i get it to also display the fail,pass, merit or distiction as well

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the range of values into tuples and these tuples then serve as keys of your dictionary. (Note that lists as keys won't work because they are not hashable.)

```
In [36]: subjects = {
   ....:     tuple(range(10)): {
   ....:         'descr': 'fail',
   ....:         'points': 0
   ....:     },
   ....:     tuple(range(10, 15)): {
   ....:         'descr': 'pass',
   ....:         'points': 25,
   ....:     },
   ....:     tuple(range(15, 18)): {
   ....:         'descr': 'merit',
   ....:         'points': 40
   ....:     },
   ....:     tuple(range(18, 21)): {
   ....:         'descr': 'Distinction',
   ....:         'points': 50
   ....:     }
   ....: }
```

You could then query the dictionary like this:

```
In [43]: score = 0

In [44]: vals = [5, 15, 20, 2, 12]

In [45]: for val in vals:
   ....:     for key in subjects:
   ....:         if val in key:
   ....:             score += subjects[key]['points']
   ....:             print subjects[key]['descr']
   ....:             break 
fail
merit
Distinction
fail
pass

In [46]: score
Out[46]: 115
```

Comment: hey peter this is not working for me(getting loads of syntax error) perhaps to advanced for me ill keep working on it

Comment: @miguel For me it works fine on Python 2.7. Where exactly do you get the errors?

Comment: on all the full stops and colons , i deleted them and then im getting it on the for just before key in subjects

Comment: @miguel Mhm, I cannot help you without seeing your code. As you can see from my updated answer, the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom ranged dictionary that looks up ranges.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

class RangeDict (dict):
    class AmbiguityException (Exception): pass

    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        hits = [ (a, b) for a, b in self.keys () if a <= key < b]
        if not hits: {} [key]
        if len (hits) > 1: raise RangeDict.AmbiguityException ()
        #for python3
        return super ().__getitem__ (hits [0] )
        #for python2.7:
        #return super (RangeDict, self).__getitem__ (hits [0] )

subjects = { (0, 9): 'fail',
    (9, 15): 'pass',
    (15, 18): 'merit',
    (18, 21): 'Distinction'}

rd = RangeDict (subjects)
for x in range (21): print (x, rd [x] )
```

EDIT: I didn't see the <kbd>python-2.7</kbd> tag. User `super (cls, inst)` instead of `super ()`.

Comment: to advanced for me only doing python 2 months , care to explain . thanks

Comment: Explanation: the RangeDict object takes ranges (p.e. 0 to 9) as keys and looks up numbers. You can do `rd [3]` and it will yield `'fail'` as 3 is inside [0, 9[.